# Inequality problem in normed space involving maximum

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Show that for every $x,y\in X$:
$$\|x+y\|\leq \max\{\|x\|,\|x+2y\|\} $$
Wanted to check two cases. First, assume the maximum is $\|x+2y\|$, then
$$\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|\leq\|x+2y\|+\|y\| $$
and stuck. the $y$-norm gets in the way of things.

Makes me think I am either going the wrong way or overlooking something. Hints, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\max{\{\|x\|,\|x+2y\|\}}&\overset{(1)}=\frac12\left(\|x\|+\|x+2y\|+\left|\|x\|-\|x+2y\|\right|\right)\\&\overset{(2)}\ge \frac12\|2x+2y\|+\frac12\left|\|x\|-\|x+2y\|\right|\\&\overset{(3)}\ge \|x+y\|\end{align} where $(1)$ holds generally for [the maximum of two numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382780/how-does-one-derive-the-formula-for-the-maximum-of-two-numbers), $(2)$ is the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) and $(3)$ is trivial.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of the equality $(1)$. Thanks a lot